# Suppose $Y|X\sim N(X,X^2)$, and $X\sim U(0,1)$, prove that $\frac YX$ and $X$ are independent.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Suppose $Y|X\sim N(X,X^2)$, and $X\sim U(0,1)$, prove that $\frac YX$ and $X$ are independent.

I only see that $\frac YX|X\sim N(0,1)$. Can anybody give some hints to complete the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the conditional distribution $\frac{Y}{X} \mid X \simeq N(0,1)$ is independent of $X$ immediately implies that $\frac{Y}{X}$ is independent of $X$. There's absolutely no need to use any transformations and/or Jacobians, as suggested by some commentators.

Comment: Is there any theorem can be used to ensure this statement?

Comment: I wouldn't call this fact even "Theorem", this is a very common knowledge. Shortly: since the conditional distribution is independent of $X$, it coincides with unconditioned distribution. Therefore, for any $A,B$, denoting $Z = \frac{Y}{X}$, 
$$
\mathrm P(Z\in A, X\in B) = \mathrm P(Z\in A| X\in B)\cdot \mathrm P( X\in B) =  \mathrm P(Z\in A)\cdot \mathrm P( X\in B).
$$

Comment: "There's absolutely no need to use any transformations and/or Jacobians" Indeed. Similarly, the distribution of X is not even needed. (+1)